# How do get the path of destination where image is saved using Glide (Image loading library Android)

Tags: android-glide

Glide uses disk caching (both internal and external). The way it stores the file name is encoded in some format. It is possible to get the original file name/file path, where the image is downloaded ?

Answer (score 1):

Glide uses a two-level cache in 3.x: `SOURCE` and `RESULT`. The default caching (if you don't specify a `.diskCacheStrategy()` is `RESULT`. Currently there's no public way to figure out which file corresponds to a normal Glide load (`RESULT` cache).

The main article about caching is: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation

[Many](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/459) [have](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/624) [tried](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/583) [to](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/517) [mess](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/552) [with](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/657) [the](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/487) [cache](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/538).

The solution is based on your use case and you can choose one of:

- `.sigunature()`: invalidate a single item in cache when signature changes
- `.downloadOnly()`: get the File handle to a SOURCE cache item
- `.asBytes()`: returns JPG/PNG encoded `byte[]` instead of a Drawable/Bitmap
- `Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache()`: last resort only, removes everything